# How can I do addition in django views?

Tags: django

When I go to add multiple integer variables, I'm getting below error. Now, what has to do?

***Error:***

```
TypeError at /
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'method' and 'int'
```

***views:***

```
total_frontend_order = request.user.user_frontend_order.all().count
total_backend_order = request.user.user_backend_order.all().count
total_complete_website_order = request.user.user_complete_website_order.all().count
a = total_frontend_order+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *call* the [**`.count()`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#count), so:

```
total_frontend_order = request.user.user_frontend_order.all().count()
total_backend_order = request.user.user_backend_order.all().count()
total_complete_website_order = request.user.user_complete_website_order.all().count()
a = total_frontend_order+1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write count()
With parenthesis.